# How can I count the number of times a specific number appears in list vertically in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to count the number of times a specific number appears in serval lists vertically.

My code:

```
import csv
with open('Superheroes.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
first_line = csvfile.readline()
super_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
result = []
for vote in super_reader:
    vote.pop(0)
    result.append([int(x) if x else 0 for x in vote])

result = [vote.count(1) for i in zip(*result)]

print(result)
```

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj9aW.png)

So from the example picture, say I wanted to know how many times the number 11 appeared in every column of all the lists. I would expect an output of [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 2]
Thanks

Comment: I am sure this can be done easily with pandas, but I would have to read the docs to check out exactly how.  Sorry if that's not even half an answer, but at least you know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` with a generator expression that outputs whether each item in a column matches the target number to perform the counting after transposing the rows into columns with `zip`:

```
def count(rows, num):
    return [sum(i == num for i in map(int, col)) for col in zip(*rows)]
```

so that given the content of `test.csv` as follows:

```
2,1,3
3,2,1
1,3,3
1,3,2
```

`count(csv.reader(open('test.csv')), 3)` would return:

```
[1, 2, 2]
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/IllAffectionateQuarks#main.py

Comment: so  I tried it and got an error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Response ID'

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Response ID'

Comment: Your CSV file has headers that can't be parsed as integers. Skip the header row with `next(csvfile)`. I've updated the demo accordingly.